# Dataframe добавление столбцов по уcловию

Tags: python, pandas

Есть две таблицы

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1234567890, 1234566690, 1235564490, 1235564590, 1234599890, 3333355555],
                   'name':['Sam', 'Andrea', 'Alex', 'Robin', 'Kia', 'Petr'],
                   'country':[14, 25, 55, 8, 21, 77]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'id_code':[12345, 12345, 12355, 12355, 12345],
                   'id_start':[67870, 66680, 64489, 64589, 99889],
                   'id_end':[67990, 66699, 64496, 64595, 99899],
                   'category':['Kino', 'Film', 'Comedy', 'ttt', 'kkk'],
                   'title':['retewrt', 'dsfsdfs', 'fsdfsfs', 'fsdewe', 'dfsdfsf']})

print(df2.loc[(df2['id_code'] == int(str(df1['id'][0])[:5])) & (df2['id_start'] <= int(str(df1['id'][0])[5:])) & (df2['id_end'] >= int(str(df1['id'][0])[5:]))])
```

нужно сделать объединение столбцов по условию id(id делиться на id_code который начинается с первого символа и заканчивается 5-м [:5] и диапазон id_start [5:] id_end[5:]) выбор строки у меня получилось сделать, но как сделать это по всей таблице и добавить эти столбцы, чтоб получилось вот так а если нет id во второй таблице то заполнить NaN:

```
           id    name  country id_code  id_start  id_end category    title
0  1234567890     Sam       14   12345     67870   67990     Kino  retewrt
1  1234566690  Andrea       25   12345     66680   66699     Film  dsfsdfs
2  1235564490    Alex       55   12355     64489   64496   Comedy  fsdfsfs
3  1235564590   Robin        8   12355     64589   64595      ttt  fsdewe
4  1234599890     Kia       21   12345     99889   99899      kkk  dfsdfsf
5  3333355555    Petr       77     NaN       NaN     NaN      NaN      NaN
```

Answer (score 2):

Не знаю, насколько верно я понял ваш вопрос, но советовал бы не писать громоздких однострочников, если вы начинаете путаться:

```
df1["id_code"] = df1["id"]//100000
df1["id_start"] = df1["id"] - df1["id_code"]*100000
res = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=["id_code"], how = "left")
res = res.loc[(res["id_start_y"]<=res["id_start_x"])&(res["id_end"]>=res["id_start_x"])]
res = pd.merge(df1, res, on="name", how="outer").drop(columns=["id_y", "country_y", "id_code_x", "id_start_y"]).rename(columns=lambda x: x.rstrip('_x'))
```

res:

```
           id    name  country  id_start  id_code_y  id_start   id_end category    title
0  1234567890     Sam       14     67890    12345.0   67890.0  67990.0     Kino  retewrt
1  1234566690  Andrea       25     66690    12345.0   66690.0  66699.0     Film  dsfsdfs
2  1235564490    Alex       55     64490    12355.0   64490.0  64496.0   Comedy  fsdfsfs
3  1235564590   Robin        8     64590    12355.0   64590.0  64595.0      ttt   fsdewe
4  1234599890     Kia       21     99890    12345.0   99890.0  99899.0      kkk  dfsdfsf
5  3333355555    Petr       77     55555        NaN       NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN
```

Comment: О, я что-то думал-думал и не догадался намержить с запасом и потом отфильтровать.

Comment: @CrazyElf ну, на мой взгляд, колхоз получился. очень неизящно как-то.

Comment: Ну может через `df.query` как-то можно было бы короче, но у меня на это способностей не хватает, а MaxU куда-то пропал как началось (

Comment: ваш метод работает, но мой df1 разрастается с 18022 строк до 1288403 строк после первого merge. в принципе не беда. И еще заметил что после выборки res.loc пропадают строки (изначально было 18022 строк после получилось 17000). Куда пропали пока не знаю буду копать.

Answer (score 1):

вот такой код вроде работает, попробуйте его потестировать:

```
indx = pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(df2.id_start,df2.id_end)
df2['intrv'] = indx
df1['id_code'] = df1.id//100000
df1['intrv'] = pd.cut(df1.id%100000,indx)
res = df1.dropna().merge(df2).drop(columns = ['intrv'])

print(res)
'''
           id    name  country  id_code  id_start  id_end category    title
0  1234567890     Sam       14    12345     67870   67990     Kino  retewrt
1  1234566690  Andrea       25    12345     66680   66699     Film  dsfsdfs
2  1235564490    Alex       55    12355     64489   64496   Comedy  fsdfsfs
3  1235564590   Robin        8    12355     64589   64595      ttt   fsdewe
4  1234599890     Kia       21    12345     99889   99899      kkk  dfsdfsf
```